# Issues with Android layout for normal sized screens

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am currently testing a recently finished app for Android and am struggling quite a bit with the layout for different screens. Basically I just can't figure out a "one size fits all" for each layout.

The normal layouts are being specially awful. On the Eclipse editor I see one thing, on the emulator I get another and on certain devices I get another. I really have no idea how to fix these screens specially because they don't appear to be wrong on the editor. Here are some examples of what I get:

What the editor looks like:

[image]

What the emulator looks like (mind you, it's the same phone on the editor):

[image]

What the screen looks like on a Motorola D3 device (the language is different, but it's the same layout!):

[image]

I don't know if it's relevant, but here is my xml code for that particular screen:

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".EnterActivityActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/recommendationTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:text="@string/recommendation_enter"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timeTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/recommendationTextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/recommendationTextView"
    android:text="@string/time_recommendation_enter" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/changeRecommendationEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/changeRecommendationtextView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/changeRecommendationtextView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/activityEnterButton"
    android:ems="5"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="5"
    android:focusable="false"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/activityEnterButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/pedometerButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/enter_button_recommendation_enter" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/pedometerButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/open_pedometer_button_recommendation_enter" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/changeRecommendationtextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/changeRecommendationButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:text="@string/change_recommendation_enter" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/changeRecommendationButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/activityEnterButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="@string/change_button_recommendation_enter" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/timeEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/recommendationTextView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/timeTextView"
    android:ems="3"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:inputType="number" 
    android:maxLength="3"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/distanceTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/timeTextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/changeRecommendationButton"
    android:text="@string/distance_recommendation_enter" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/distanceEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/changeRecommendationButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/timeTextView"
    android:ems="5"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:inputType="number" 
    android:maxLength="5"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

How exactly could I fix this so that is actually looks good and consistent with all the varieties of screens and devices?

Comment: you simulator is running android 2.3 and  does not use the same theme as the device and the editor

Comment: The problem is you're using a lot of hard coded values for those margins that originally seemed to work well on the screen. If, for instance, you would have been developed from the start on a smaller screen, then the layout probably turned out to be bad for a bigger screen. Try to use a vertical Linear Layout instead and play with those gravity properties.

Comment: Before fixing anything make sure you read this page if you haven't already: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html.

Comment: theJuls, you must need to follow, android guidlines to draw layout for all the screens, I think you have used lots of static values in it and that is the problem.